# Exception : Fsharp

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a code for axure api implementation, which is a c# code, but it is throwing an exception:

Code is :

```
RPPage rpPage = (RPPage)doc.LoadPackage((RPPackageHandle)child.NodeValue);
```

> Exception : Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I don't know how to add this library. I can't find such library on internet.
Please share how to get this library or please also share if any alternate solution is available for this problem.

Thnaks!!!

Comment: Are you shure,that target framework of your project is .NET 4.0?

Comment: You should read the about [Notes and Guidance on FSharp.Core](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html)

Comment: so, it was conflict with frameworks?

Comment: @Dr_klo - What is your suggestion on this please..?

Comment: @ManojSingh you changed target framework from 4.5 to 4 and its work well or you set 4.0 and still get error? or target already is 4.0?

Comment: target is already 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a reference to FSharp.Core nuget package using

`Install-Package FSharp.Core -Version 4.0.0.1`

This will install the Nuget Package into your Application.

**OPTIONAL**

Depending on the Scenario. you might also need to add the necessary Binding Redirect Flags in your `Web.Config` or `App.Config`

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity 
       name="FSharp.Core" 
       publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
       culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This forces all FSharp related dependencies to use the version that you just installed